# Turn off import.sql in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

This is an under documented part of hibernate, but if a file named import.sql exists in the root of the class path `('/import.sql')` Hibernate will execute the SQL statements read from the file after the creation of the database schema. I was wondering if there was a way to turn this off on hibernate. The obvious answer is to change the name from import.sql, but I was wondering if there was another way. Perhaps through the hibernate properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give a try by setting the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files` property to an empty string.

As you can see in the source code of `SchemaExport`, tries to load the files specified by the property and returns the DEFAULT_IMPORT_FILE if the configuration does not contains a value :

```
    this.importFiles = ConfigurationHelper.getString(
            AvailableSettings.HBM2DDL_IMPORT_FILES,
            configuration.getProperties(),
            DEFAULT_IMPORT_FILE
    );
```

M.

Comment: I have the Hibernate source code on my computer. You can find it on the internet for instance the ConfigurationHelper: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.0.0.Alpha2/org/hibernate/internal/util/config/ConfigurationHelper.java#ConfigurationHelper.getString%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.util.Map%29 . The rest is from the hibernate-core/src/main/java/org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.* package HIH

Comment: I did some more research and it says this feature was available since 3.6. So i might have been preemptive when saying this does not work as it should. I will update my hibernate version and if it helps, I will accept. Thanks for your help!